# android textview settext show nullpointer exception

Tags: android, textview

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/first_name"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/black"
android:textColor="@color/light_grey"
android:text="FirstName"
></TextView>

TextView first_text_view;

first_text_view = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.first_name);
try {
first_text_view.setText("Android");
}catch(Exception e) {
}
```

i got the nullpointer exception.

what is solution for this. please reply me

Answer (score 6):

Well, seems that `findViewById` returns `null`. This is probably the case, because `this` does not refer to the Activity or you're not assigning the View to the Activity in `onCreate` (you have to call `setContentView` in `onCreate`).

Comment: thanks jleedev i got the output, actually i confuse the setcontentview method location. now i am cleared