# Getting And Displaying Date Info In Android

Tags: java, android, calendar, logcat, forceclose

Currently I am trying to get the date (Month and Year specifically) and display it using a TextView but my program is force closing.

Here is where I "get" the month and year.

```
Calendar cCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
int currentYear = cCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int currentMonth = cCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

Here is where I set the TextView text.

```
public void setDateLabel(View v)
{
    TextView month = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.monthLabel);
    TextView year = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yearLabel);
    year.setText(currentYear);
    month.setText(currentMonth);
}
```

Here is the XML with the TextView and Button.

```
<TextView android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:text="TextView" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/monthLabel"></TextView>
<TextView android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:text="TextView" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/yearLabel"></TextView>
<Button android:text="Button" android:onClick="setDateLabel" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/setDate"></Button>
```

I try to run it in Debug to get a LogCat but the debugger just stops and waits for it to "attach" on port 8634.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When are you calling 'public void setDateLabel(View v)
'

Comment: It seems your call to 'findViewById' is returning null. Found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361509/android-textview-settext-show-nullpointer-exception), does it help?